# Background 'Page Name' dialog box doesn't update in SharePoint

Tags: background

I have 3 background pages, which have a field dialog box at the top for the tab's name, (so "Page name")... I also have the page number and total pages at the bottom using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/643097/display-visio-page-title-in-page).

Every foreground page in the Visio file has the appropriate background applied to it, and the dialogue boxes show the correct page name and number when displayed in Visio on the desktop. However, when I upload this Visio file to the SharePoint site, every page has the name of its background page at the top... and has 0/"the correct amount of pages" at the bottom.

More curious still, when I "save as PDF" from SharePoint, all of the headers start to work again, and the page numbers are all correct.

Is there a setting I'm missing, or something with the SharePoint that isn't set up correctly that means these fields aren't working when uploaded? I'm at a Loss. I tried saving as .VDW but that was even worse, and the central portion of the heading was not rendered correctly and was still *trying* to display the background's name.